# How to transfer purchases from iPhone into iTunes library

Tags: itunes

While trying to sync my phone and update new information this came up.

> There are purchased items on the iPhone “iPhone” that have not been transferred to your iTunes library.  You should transfer these items to your iTunes library before updating this iPhone.  Are you sure you want to continue?

How do I do this?

Answer (score 16):

You can do this in the iTunes menu at the top of the screen: `File :: Devices :: Transfer purchases`

As simple as that.

Comment: Why is it important to do this? What difference does it make?

Comment: @ChristopheWeibel Its not important anymore, because you can recover purchases from iCloud. It was not the case 3 years ago.

Comment: Can you clarify whether these apply only to items purchase at the iTunes store?

Comment: Update from 2022: sometimes this does not help, and after this iTunes pops up with the same message 

Answer (score 1):

You'd better transfer your purchases first.

- Connect your device to the computer. Wait for its icon to appear in iTunes.
- Go to File > Devices. If you're using iTunes for Windows and can't see the menu bar, learn how to turn on iTunes menus in Windows (http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202662).
- Choose Transfer Purchases from [device name].

Comment: But what do you do when you've done that and still get the message?

Comment: @ShadSterling [reauthorize your computer in iTunes](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201251), and then, try again.

Comment: I did that from iTunes on my windows, and it give me a quick indication that there is some activity. Then I keep receiving the same warning when I try to update the system.